# what would the output of the program?

Tags: java, try-catch, stringbuilder, finally

the output is coming as Test Passed!!! how the builder return when it is set to null at finally block

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(new Test().print());
    }
    protected StringBuilder print() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            builder.append("Test ");
            return builder.append("Passed!!!");
        } finally {
            builder = null; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, finally is executed whether or not there is an exception.  Maybe you are confusing catch block

Comment: You asked this like 7 hours ago....and there's it's been answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the result of the `return` is a copy of the reference of the `builder` in that moment.

`builder = null;` in `finally` code doesn't alter this reference, instead just replaces the current value of the `builder` variable inside `print` method.

Still, note that if you alter the state of the object reference that is returned, this will affect the result of the returned value. For example:

```
protected StringBuilder print() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        builder.append("Test ");
        return builder.append("Passed!!!");
    } finally {
        builder.append(" but modified!");
        //builder = null; 
    }
}
```

It will print:

```
Test Passed!!! but modified!
```

Answer (score 0):

`finally` happens after everything else. This means builder will be set to null after the return (but of course, before the caller gets the result.

Note that nulling builder doesn't make much sense in this case since the builder variable is about to fall out of scope and will be cleaned up by garbage collection at some point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you returned the StringBuilder contents and THEN set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

`finally` is executed after try block either the execption is generated or not.Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for your reference from Java documentation.